# Unity configuration error - type does not have constructor that takes parameters

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

Background: I have a helper class that I use to set the policies for the `ExceptionManager`. In this class I want to inject various implementations of the `IExceptionHandler` interface and I want to control this via a configuration file.

So this is how things look:
**Helper class and interface:**

```
public class ErrorHelper: IErrorHelper
{
    private static IExceptionHandler _exceptionHandler;
    public ErrorHelper(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler)
    {
        _exceptionHandler = exceptionHandler;
    }

    public IList<ExeptionPolicyDefinition> GetPolicies()
    {
        //Do stuff here and return policies
        //This is the place where _exceptionHandler is used
    }
}
public interface IErrorHelper
{
    IList<ExeptionPolicyDefinition> GetPolicies();
}
```

**IExceptionHandler implementation:**

```
public class MyExceptionHandler: IExceptionHandler
{
    public MyExceptionHandler()
    {
        //Do some stuff here
    }
    public Exception HandleException(Exception exp, Guid iId)
    {
        //Handle exception and log
    }
}
```

**The unity bootstrap class:**

```
public class UnityBootstrap
{
    private static IUnityContainer _unityContainer;
    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _unityContainer = container;
        var section = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
        section.Configure(_unityContainer);
    }
    public static void SetPolicies()
    {
        var helper = _unityContainer.Resolve<IErrorHelper>();
        //Set ExceptionManager and ExceptionPolicy
    }
}
```

**Unity configuration file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unity xmlns="http://schemas/microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <alias alias="IExceptionHandler" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.IExceptionHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <alias alias="MyExceptionHandler" type="TEST.Shared.MyExceptionHandler, Test.Shared"/>
    <alias alias="ErrorHelper" type="TEST.Helpers.Errorhelper, TEST.Helpers"/>
    <alias alias="IErrorHelper" type="TEST.Helpers.IErrorhelper, TEST.Helpers"/>
    <container>
        <register type="IExceptionHandler" mapTo="MyExceptionHandler"/>
        <register type="IErrorHelper" mapTo="ErrorHelper">
             <constructor>
                 <param name="exceptionHandler" type="MyExceptionHandler">
                     <dependency type="MyExceptionHandler"/>
                 </param>
             </constructor>
        </register>
    </container>
</unity>
```

So, after a lot of writing and formatting, this is a simplification of what I have. The problem is that when I call `RegisterTypes` I get the error in the title, stating that there is no constructor for `ErrorHelper` that accepts parameters of name `exceptionHandler` when clearly the parameter name in the constructor is `exceptionHandler`.

If anyone can point to where I'm going wrong with this please do.

PS1: Sorry for the long question

PS2: I'm pretty new to DI and Unity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the parameter in the constructor is IExceptionHandler not MyExceptionHandler.

Try: `<param name="exceptionHandler" type="IExceptionHandler">`

Comment: Well now, I can't believe it was that obvious that it was practically staring me in the face. Thanks, that did the trick.